# First letter capital in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to ensure first letter is capital in Snowflake for full name field?

Input : DAVID BILLY ALEX ANDERSON

Expected Output : David Billy Alex Anderson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[INITCAP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/initcap.html) is what you are looking for:

```
select 'DAVID BILLY ALEX ANDERSON' as inp, initcap(inp) as outp;
```

| INP | OUTP |
| --- | --- |
| DAVID BILLY ALEX ANDERSON | David Billy Alex Anderson |

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will this work for non-english characters also ?

Comment: @Shruti Did you read any of the documentation link, and look at the multilanguage answers, or even try it?